# writing a replace() method for linked list class

Tags: java, replace, linked-list

I'm having trouble writing a `replace()` method for a class I'm building called `LString`. The class creates a linked list object for building strings, similar to `String` or `StringBuilder` but with linked lists instead of arrays.

The `replace(int start, int end, LString lStr)` is a method that alters the given `LString`, a linked list, by inserting another `LString` called `lStr` between the nodes of `start` and `end`. I'm struggling to think of an efficient way to write it. Any advice is appreciated, trying to learn Java.

Here is my code, `replace()` is near the bottom:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LString    {

     node   front;
     int size;

     //Creating a node class
     private    class   node {
          char data;
          node next;

          public    node (){
          }

          public    node    (char   newData){
                this.data = newData;
          }

          public    node    (char   newData,    node newNext){
                this.data = newData;
                this.next = newNext;
          }


     }
     //Constructors
     public LString(){
          this.size =   0;
          this.front =  null;
     }
     public LString(String original)    {
          this.size = original.length();
          if (original.length() > 0){

              this.front =  new node(original.charAt(0));
              node curr = this.front;

              for   (int i =1; i <  original.length(); i++) {
                    curr.next = new node(original.charAt(i));
                    curr = curr.next;
              }
          }



     }

    //  Length method,  returns the length of LString
     public int length()    {
        return this.size;
    }

    //  compareTo method,   compares    this LString to anotherLString, returns 0   if  equal,
    //  -1  if  lexicogrpahically   less,   and 1   if  lexicographically   greater
    public int compareTo(LString anotherLString)    {
        int len1    = length();
        int len2    = anotherLString.length();
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);

        node cn1    = front;
        node cn2    = anotherLString.front;

        int k   = 0;
        while   (k  < lim) {
            char c1 = cn1.data;
            char c2 = cn2.data;
            if  (c1 != c2) {
                return c1-c2;
            }
            k++;
            cn1 =   cn1.next;
            cn2 =   cn2.next;
        }
        return len1 - len2;

    }

    //  a boolean equals method that returns true   if  LString and other   are the same, false if not
    public boolean  equals(Object other)    {
        if  (this   ==  other) {
            return true;
        }
        if  (other instanceof   LString)    {
            LString otherLString    = (LString)other;
            int n   = length();
            if  (n  ==  otherLString.length()) {
                node n1 = front;
                node n2 = otherLString.front;

                while   (n1 != null) {
                    if  (n1.data    !=  n2.data)    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    n1  = n1.next;
                    n2  = n2.next;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    //  charAt returns  the character of LString at the argument index
    public char charAt(int index)   {

        if  ((index < 0) || (index >= this.length()))   {
            throw   new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        node curNode =  front;
        for (int    i = 0; i    < this.length(); i++, curNode   = curNode.next) {
            if  (i  ==  index) {
                return curNode.data;
            }
        }
        throw   new IllegalStateException();
    }

    //
    public void setCharAt(int index,    char ch)    {
      if (index < 0 || index >= this.length()) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
      else {
         node currNode = front;
         for (int i = 0; i <this.length(); i++, currNode = currNode.next) {
            if (i == index) {
            currNode.data = ch;
            }
         }
      }
   }

    public LString  substring(int start,    int end)    {
      if (start < 0 || end > this.length() || start > end) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
      LString substring = new LString();
      if (start == end) {
         return substring;
      }
      node node = this.front;
      for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
         node = node.next;
      }
      node copy = new node(node.data);
      substring.front = copy;
      for (int i = start+1; i < end; i++) {
         node = node.next;
         copy = copy.next = new node(node.data);
      }
      substring.size = end - start;
      return substring;      
    }
    public LString  replace(int start, int end, LString lStr)   {
        if (start < 0 || end > this.length() || start > end) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }//??
    }

    public void append(char data){

        this.size++;

        if  (front == null){
             front =    new node(data);
             return;
        }

        node curr = front;
        while   (curr.next != null){
             curr   = curr.next;
        }

        curr.next = new node(data);

    }

    public void prepend (char data){

        front   = new   node(data, front);
        size++;
    }


    public void delete(int index){

        if  (index == 0){
             front =    front.next;
        } else {
             node   curr = front;
             for (int i = 0; i <    index   - 1; i++){
                curr = curr.next;
             }
             curr.next = curr.next.next;
        }
        size--;

    }


    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder result    = new   StringBuilder();

        node curr = front;
        while   (curr   !=  null){

            result.append(curr.data);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public void add(int index,  char data){
         if (index == 0){
              front = new node(data, front);
         }  else {
              node curr = front;
              for   (int i =    0;  i < index - 1;  i++){
                    curr = curr.next;
              }
              curr.next = new   node(data, curr.next);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` already exists. Why are you doing this? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865738/substring-method-for-linked-list-object)? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847451/writing-charat-and-setcharat-methods-for-linked-list-class)? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844026/writing-an-equals-method-for-linked-list-object)? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824474/lstring-class-using-linked-lists-to-make-strings-java)? And how long is this going to continue? Every time you add a method?

Comment: I am a regular user of StackOverflow who has asked you a question. You haven't answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the replace method

```
public LString  replace(int start, int end, LString lStr)   {
    if (start < 0 || end > this.length() || start > end) {
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
  }

  LString repString = new LString();

  node node = this.front;
  node cpy = new node(node.data);

  repString.front = cpy;

  for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
     node  = node.next;
     cpy = cpy.next = new node(node.data);
  }
  node nIt = node;
  node =  lStr.front;

  for (int i = start+1; i < end; i++) {
        node  = node.next;
        nIt = nIt.next;
        cpy = cpy.next = new node(node.data);
  }
  node = nIt;
  for (int i = end; i < this.length(); i++) {
      node  = node.next;
     cpy = cpy.next = new node(node.data);
  }

  return repString;

}
```

for your coding practice.

- Always make the first letter of a class name Capital (example: `private class Node`) in Java
- Use methods to get the properties or fields in the Object (example: `node.next()).`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `replace()` method returns an `LString`, I'm assuming you want the result to be a copy. Otherwise I'd propose in-place replacement since `LString` is mutable.

Here's a tested and functional implementation for you to consider.

```
public LString replace(int start, int end, LString lStr) {
    if (start < 0 || end > length() || start > end) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    LString result = new LString();
    node node = this.front;
    node copy = new node(node.data);
    result.front = copy;
    for (int i = 1; i < start; i++) {
        node = node.next;
        copy = copy.next = new node(node.data);
    }
    node replace = lStr.front;
    for (int i = 0; i < lStr.length(); i++) {
        copy = copy.next = new node(replace.data);
        replace = replace.next;
    }
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        node = node.next;
    }
    for (int i = end; i < length(); i++) {
        node = node.next;
        copy = copy.next = new node(node.data);
    }
    result.size = length() + lStr.length() - (end - start);
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately the code in the other answer is bugged. It looks like @Jemaro copied the `substring()` method from my other answer and tried to make it suitable for this without testing, but didn't succeed.